# Advanced Clipboard - more data stored C#/Windows

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard

I have to write a program which extends my Windows clipboard and allows to store more data while copy/paste a file. It must work like that: I'm coping a file, and paste it into, for example, Outlook and it recognize it as a file, which is normally happening when you do this action (clipboard stores path). However, when I paste this file to, for example, notepad I want it to paste file name.

Is it possible to extend clipboard like this? I'd be thankful for any tip.

[EDIT] FileDropList contains only collection of strings with full file names (paths). I need to store more data in that.

Comment: You could put the file name back onto the clipboard as CF_TEXT, and Notepad would paste it.  But with apps that can handle both formats, you will have various results. Some will paste files, some will paste the text.

Comment: @Chris Thornton Could you explain me how to put to Clipboard both FileDropList and a text value assigned to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found following solutions:

It's possible to add several data to a DataObject, but they need to be different types. Therefore I add one list with files to copy and one long string, where I add file names separated with "\n" or " ".

If someone needs to put several values of the same type can define own object (class, struct) - must be serialized! - and put your values there. Unfortunately this object can be recognised only by your app.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple formats you could use DataObject as container for your value like this:

### SET

```
        var obj1 = new DataObject(DataFormats.Text,Yourobj.asText());
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj1);

        var obj2 = new DataObject(DataFormats.Html,Yourobj.asHtml());
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj2);
```

### GET

```
        IDataObject data_object = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        if (data_object.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Html))
           var yourHTML =data_object.GetData(DataFormats.Html);
```

Comment: The point is not to store object of different types, but to return type that specific application can handle.

Comment: @Niko so the point **IS** to store object of different types, because how will you know which type which application needs ... and when the user is trying to past the object in what app

Comment: So I have to create a few objects of different type representing in fact the same file?
However file path and file name are both strings. What will simple application like notepad do in that case?

Comment: @Niko DataObject is a .Net Class so can do something like: `Clipboard.SetDataObject(new DataObject(DataFormats.Text,Yourobj.getFilepath()));` the only Question her is what `DataFormats` does the App ( e.g. Outlook) expect todo what ever you think it should do

Comment: I know that, but in Clipboard I can keep just one DataObject, can't I? In that concept I'd have to keep there a faw objects for one file (one for path, one for name, etc) and objects for those objects in case I'd like to copy a faw files per time.

Comment: @Niko as far as i have looked throw Blogs, you can have more then one DataObject